# How to search dates in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I would like to compare a date entered in a search field (e.g., 04.07.2012) with a date from my table (a `datetime` column called `date`). However, I can't seem to get my SQL query straight.

What I tried:

```
find(:all, :conditions => ['\'to_timestamp(date, \'DD Mon YYYY\')\' LIKE \'to_timestamp(?, \'DD Mon YYYY\')\'', '#{query}'])
```

but it fails:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DD"
LINE 1: ...s".* FROM "projects"  WHERE ('to_timestamp(date, 'DD Mon YYY...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "pacients".* FROM "projects"  WHERE ('to_timestamp(date, 'DD Mon YYYY')' LIKE 'to_timestamp('#{query}', 'DD Mon YYYY')')
```

I'm a real novice as far as (postgre)SQL is concerned and I would really appreciate some hints in the right direction of writing this query.

Thanks a million!

Comment: Be sure to understand the difference between [data types `timestamp` and `date`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As meager pointed out there are a couple of issues here:

- incorrect string interpolation
- making the database do more work than necessary and using `LIKE` when you can do date searching more directly:

Let ActiveRecord format the date inputs use straight SQL to compare the dates, something like:

```
start_date = Date.civil(2012, 7, 4)
end_date = Date.civil(2012, 7, 20)
User.where(["date BETWEEN ? AND ?", start_date, end_date])
```

Converting the source date and the dates in the database to a timestamp formatted like a string and then using `LIKE` is very round-about and poor performing as well.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I used in the end.
In my project.rb model: 

`def self.search(query)
 begin
  if query
   Project.where(["date BETWEEN ? AND ?", Date.parse(query), Date.parse(query)])
  else
   Project.all
     end
 rescue ArgumentError 
  Project.all
 end`